# Volley does not stop adding date to listview from json

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

I want app to show dates in listview. My app has `TabLayout` which imitates [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) and `Listviews` which imitate [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/).So, tabs have listview. After showing all json dates in listview, they load json dates again.
 It happens when I swipe each tabs like `tab1→tab2→tab3→tab1→tab3...`. 
This is may code. If anyone knows what is wrong, please teach me.

```
public class AppController extends Application {
public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}
public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}
public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

Tab 1 (Tab2 and Tab3 are almost same)

```
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    adapter = new CSadapter(getActivity(),movieList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();
                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Song movie = new Song();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("jacket"));
                            movie.setNumber(obj.getString("number"));
                            movie.setYear(obj.getString("release"));
                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();
        }
    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}
```

Comment: In a pager the default page limit is 1 .If you go beyond that your page activity is created again.This may be the case happening here.You can increase the page limit to avoid re creation

Comment: Thank you advice! I added `setOffscreenPageLimit()`. My app does not reload json date again!<br>But I added tabs and `setOffscreenPageLimit(4)` because app has 5tabs, it need to take a time to show first screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a pager the default page limit is 1 .If you go beyond that your page activity is created again.This may be the case happening here.You can increase the page limit to avoid re creation